# Google API error in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I work in Google map in android

I add Google API API17 REV3

but error appear to me:

```
[2013-07-29 10:24:09 - googlemap] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
[2013-07-29 10:24:09 - googlemap] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2013-07-29 10:24:09 - googlemap] Launch canceled!
```

main.xml:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/themap"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="mykeyapi" />
```

my code is:

```
    MapView view=(MapView) findViewById(R.id.themap);
    view.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

and I add to manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

AND

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.anroid.maps"/>
```

and create AVD Google API

but error appear to me why??!!!!!!!!!

Comment: What does logcat say?

Comment: A tip: Please don't share your ACTUAL `apikey` for security reasons. It will be good for you :)

Comment: [2013-07-29 10:24:09 - googlemap] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY [2013-07-29 10:24:09 - googlemap] Please check logcat output for more details. [2013-07-29 10:24:09 - googlemap] Launch canceled!

Comment: Package com.example.googlemap requires unavailable shared library com.google.anroid.maps; failing!

Comment: you are using google map api v1

Comment: ok how use google map v3

Comment: @NiceMan: Google Map V3 for JavaScript And Web App & Google Map V2 for Android check this ---> http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-google-map-v2-part-1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the new Google Maps API, from what i remember,  isn't necessary anymore in the Manifest file.

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="api key"/>

<permission
    android:name="[package].MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="[package].permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

Comment: Are you using maps v2 ?. have you downloaded Google Play services from your SDK, added it to your workspace and set it as library on your project properties?

Comment: no using maps v3
and I add Google Play service
but how add to workspace

Comment: Import Existing Android Code Into Project
adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services

Comment: then after importing it, right click on your project, properties, Android then add as library.

Comment: are you mean put my code into  adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services

then add as library???

Comment: No.. Import google_play_services into your IDE as an existing android code. Then right click on your project and add google_play_services as a library.

Comment: ur welcome.. is it okay now? if it is, please set this as the correct answer. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

please check the `project.properties` file it should be target like that any of api version

```
target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:8
```

Comment: you can use android google map api v2 try to folloew this link http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/07/google-map-android-api-v2-with-location.html

Answer (score 0):

You must be missing your **maps.jar** to include for this you need to add this explicitly

that is in your following path

```
dir:\..\..\android-sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-8\libs
```

add this to ypur project clean it and run it it will work

your Map permission require in manifest file is following

```
<permission
android:name="packagename.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="packagename.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

replace packagename with your project package name like "com.android.exapmle"

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/ApiKey" />
```